# How to specify git author/committer for PullRequest merge in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have defined a release pipeline to synchronize code between two git repositories in Azure DevOps. The process requires a PullRequest in the destination repo which is created and completed using the WebAPI.

The pipeline is executed by the build agent running using a Windows domain service account. So, the PullRequest is created and completed on behalf of the service account, which is also mentioned as author, committer, etc. in the git history after merge is completed. (According to our rules the PR must be merged using squash commit.)

**I would like see a different user in the git history after (squash) merge.**

Can I specify the user (e.g. the user triggering the release pipeline) using WebAPI?
I did not find such option in the API documentation.

Any other recommendation? Maybe convention like adding "co-authored-by" to commit message like github?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [Pull Requests-Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to create a pull request, **the pull request creator is determined by the creator of the PAT you used for authentication** (e.g. I used the PAT of hughl01 user as the authentication to create the pull request, then the creator of the pull request is hughl01).

Test in Postman:

[image]

[image]

Sample test script in powershell task:

```
$token = "{User-created PAT}"

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/dev2",
  "targetRefName": "refs/heads/master",
  "title": "ForTest",
  "description": "Adding a new feature"
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON
```

You can create a variable group, with the release trigger as the variable name, and the PAT corresponding to the user as the variable value and set the value of the variable to secret. Then get the name of the triggerer through the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release) `$(Release.RequestedFor)` in the script, then obtain the corresponding PAT according to the trigger name to create pull request.

Comment: This requires to have access to the PAT of the user, isn't it? But I want to create the PR for the user which has started the release pipeline (RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR*).

Comment: **pull request creator is determined by the creator of the PAT**, so you can create a variable group, with the release trigger as the variable name, and the PAT corresponding to the user as the variable value. Get the name of the triggerer through the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release) `$(Release.RequestedFor)` in the script, then obtain the corresponding PAT according to the trigger name to create  pull request.

Comment: Do you mean, I should create one variable group for every (potentially) creator of the release? Or one variable group with PAT for all (potentially) creators? In both cases I need to request and configure PAT for all (potentially) creators!?

Comment: Yes, if you want to modify the author, as far as I know, we can only use this method. You can set the value of the variable to secret. Although these will be a bit cumbersome

Comment: So, I think, this should be part of your solution and not only a side note (comment). Would you rework your solution, than I take it as the solution, even it is not the expected one.

Comment: @lg2de Thanks for the reminder, I have updated the answer. Have a nice day.  :)